# Match two Arrays and return the address of the match cell then copy the next column of that cell

Tags: vba, excel

In one Worksheets,

- i have in Column A values from 1 to 10, they are separated by three empty rows, means value1 in A1, value2 in A4 and so on.
- In column B i have numbers but in random order but they are within the limit of the range in column A, it means if max value in column A is 15, any value in B range will never exceed 15, and the values in B are posted in the same rows as values of A.
- In column C i have values for each number in B range, i have 4 answers attached to it. so for the first value in B1, i have C1,C2,C3,C4 and so on.

Now what i want to do is: i want to match the values in Column B with A then copy the four values of C and paste then in D where the match value found.

for example if i have 5 as first value in column B i want to check where this value is in column A then copy C1,C2,C3,C4 and paste them in front of the 5 in column A
I want to do that using Arrays.

I already wrote a macro to do that using a loop and match function, but it's not very practical as i have many files to loop through and have long A and B columns so it takes time and it has many other limitations,**So is there another way to achieve this goal, using Arrays for example? and if i used two arrays for Range A and Range B, how can i use the match function or lockup to compare them?** this is my macro:

```
Dim see As Worksheet
Set see = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim rega As Range
Dim numb As Long
Dim tr As Integer
Dim dd As Long
With see
    Set rega = .Range(.Cells(3, gh + 2).Address, .Cells(23, gh + 2).Address)
End With
For tr = 3 To 40 Step 4
    numb = M.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(see.Cells(tr, 1 + gh), rega, 0)
    For dd = 0 To 3
        see.Cells(numb + dd, gh + 3).Copy
        see.Cells(te + dd, gh + 4).PasteSpecial
    Next dd
Next
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Too much information. You should cut down your post to keep only the essentials. This will increase your chance of getting help. For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, I still don't see a question.

Comment: Now what i want to do is: i want to match the values in Column B with A then copy the four values of C and paste then in D where the match value found.

for example if i have 5 as first value in column B i want to check where this value is in column A then copy C1,C2,C3,C4 and paste them in front of the 5 in column A I want to do that using Arrays.

Comment: That's not a question. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: It was there but removed by the auto correction, it should be more clear now. sorry for the my bad way of writing questions

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of at least one loop and convert the *Copy, Paste Special* to direct value transfer.

```
With see
    Set rega = .Range(.Cells(3, gh + 2).Address, .Cells(23, gh + 2).Address)
    For tr = 3 To 40 Step 4
        numb = M.Application.Match(.Cells(tr, 1 + gh), rega, 0)
        .Cells(tr, gh + 4).resize(4, 1) = .Cells(numb, gh + 3).resize(4, 1).value
    Next tr
End With
```

... instead of,

```
With see
    Set rega = .Range(.Cells(3, gh + 2).Address, .Cells(23, gh + 2).Address)
End With
For tr = 3 To 40 Step 4
    numb = M.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(see.Cells(tr, 1 + gh), rega, 0)
    For dd = 0 To 3
        see.Cells(numb + dd, gh + 3).Copy
        see.Cells(te + dd, gh + 4).PasteSpecial
    Next dd
Next
```

(I assumed a typo and changed `see.Cells(te, gh + 4)` to `see.Cells(tr, gh + 4)`)

Other than that, I do not have much to recommend other than turning off events, calculation and screen updating.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

' run all the code

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```